# Переменная становится undefined внутри else

Tags: jquery, if, undefined-reference

Всем привет. Вот часть моего кода в jquery. Здесь должно происходить сокрытие блока menu влево, при нажатии кнопки, с помощью `margin-left` и, соответственно, увеличение размера блока `article` до 100% ширины экрана.
При повторном же нажатии на эту кнопку, происходит обратное действие.

В чем проблема:

При первичном нажатии, все идет как надо. Переменная `menuWidth` прекрасно подставляется в css. Но вот при повторном нажатии, блок `menu` возвращается на свое место, а `margin-left`, который принадлежит `article` не понимает, что такое `newMenuWidth` (т.е. article не возвращается на свое место. Это можно увидеть по кнопке, которая остается на том же месте). Попытка изменить переменную на `menuWidth` тоже ничего не дает. Если выводить в консоль, то `newMenuWidth` и `menuWidth` до **else** имеют числовое значение, а после **else** принимают значение **undefined**.

Не понимаю, в чем проблема. Везде пишут, если переменная undefined, значит у нее нет значения. Но я же задаю ей значение через var. Не может же оно исчезнуть в той же функции. Помогите, пожалуйста, где я делаю ошибку?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menusWidth = $('.menu').width();
    $('.article').css("margin-left", menusWidth);
    var menu = $(".menu");
    var article = $(".article");
    var sizeLine = $("#sizeLine");
    
    var curr_width = menu.width()
    var unlock = false;
    
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        $(".menu").css("transition", "0ms");
        var userCursor = parseFloat(e.clientX * 100 / screen.width);
    var change = userCursor*screen.width/100;
          var textWidth = screen.width - change;
    var menuMin= screen.width/100*15;
       if(unlock) {
       if(change > (menuMin-1)){
        menu.css("width", change);
                    article.css("width", screen.width-change);
                    $('.article').css("margin-left", change);
                        if (parseInt($('.article').css('margin-left')) > screen.width/100*40) {
                            $('.article').css('margin-left', screen.width/100*40);
                        }
                    sizeLine.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)");
       }
       else {
        menu.css("width", screen.width/100*15);
                    article.css("width", screen.width/100*85);
                    $('.article').css("margin-left", menusWidth);
                    sizeLine.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)");
            }
        }
    });

    sizeLine.mouseenter(function(e) {
        sizeLine.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)");
    })

    sizeLine.mouseleave(function(e) {
        sizeLine.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    })

    sizeLine.mousedown(function(e) {
        curr_width = menu.width();
        unlock = true;
    });

    $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        if(unlock) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        unlock = false;
        sizeLine.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)");
    });
});

var num = 0;
$('#menuButton').click(function() { 
    if (num%2 == 0) {
        var menuWidth = $(".menu").width();
        $(".menu").css("margin-left", -menuWidth);
        $(".menu").css("transition", "300ms");
        $(".article").css("width", screen.width);
        $(".article").css("margin-left", 0);
        num += 1; 
        var newMenuWidth = menuWidth;
    } else {
        $(".menu").css("width", newMenuWidth);
        $(".menu").css("margin-left", 0);
        $(".menu").css("transition", "300ms");
        $(".article").css("width", screen.width-newMenuWidth);
        $(".article").css("margin-left", newMenuWidth);
        num += 1;
    }
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 font-family: 'Helvetica','Sans-Serif'; 
}

.menu {
 width: 15%;
 min-width: 290px;
 max-width: 40%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #f2f2f2;
 font-size: 18px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 resize: horizontal;
 overflow: none;
 position: fixed;
}

.menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


.treeMenu {
 margin: 40px 0 5px -20px;
}

#sizeLine {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: e-resize;
}

.article {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 width: 85%;
 min-width: 60%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #ffffff;
}

.header {
 height: 60px;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}

#menuButton {
 width: 30px;
 height: 40px;
 border: 0;
 margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
 background: #666666 no-repeat center;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

#menuButton:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 transition: 0.3;
}

.content {
 width: 900px;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0 auto 0;
 display: flex;
 text-align: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.contentBox {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>owl</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <!-- Меню --> 

 <div class="menu">
  <ol class="treeMenu">
   <li>Пункт1</li>
   <li id="name2">Пункт2
    <ol id="pp2">
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
    </ol>
   </li>
   <li id="name3">Пункт3
    <ol id="pp3">
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a>
      <ol id="ppp33">
       <li><a href="#">Подподпункт</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Подподпункт</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Подподпункт</a></li>
      </ol>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
    </ol>
   </li>
   <li>Пункт4</li>
   <li id="name5">Пункт5
    <ol id="pp5">
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Подпункт</a></li>
    </ol>
   </li>
  </ol>
  <div id="sizeLine"></div>
 </div>


 <div class="article">
  <div class="header">
   <input type="button" name="menuButton" id="menuButton">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="contentBox">

<h1>Это контент</h1>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
  var num = 0;
$('#menuButton').click(function() { 
    if (num%2 == 0) {
        var menuWidth = $(".menu").width();
        $(".menu").css("margin-left", -menuWidth);
        $(".menu").css("transition", "300ms");
        $(".article").css("width", screen.width);
        $(".article").css("margin-left", 0);
        num += 1; 
        var newMenuWidth = menuWidth;
    } else {
        $(".menu").css("width", newMenuWidth);
        $(".menu").css("margin-left", 0);
        $(".menu").css("transition", "300ms");
        $(".article").css("width", screen.width-newMenuWidth);
        $(".article").css("margin-left", newMenuWidth);
        num += 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменную надо объявить снаружи функции-обработчика. Тогда эта переменная будет сохранять свое значение между кликами.

```
var newMenuWidth = null;
$('#menuButton').click(function() { 
    if (newMenuWidth == null) {
        var menuWidth = $(".menu").width();
        $(".menu").css("margin-left", -menuWidth);
        $(".menu").css("transition", "300ms");
        $(".article").css("width", screen.width);
        $(".article").css("margin-left", 0);
        newMenuWidth = menuWidth;
    } else {
        $(".menu").css("width", newMenuWidth);
        $(".menu").css("margin-left", 0);
        $(".menu").css("transition", "300ms");
        $(".article").css("width", screen.width-newMenuWidth);
        $(".article").css("margin-left", newMenuWidth);
        newMenuWidth = null;
    }
});
```